# Running Tomcat in Eclipse and getting "Exception loading sessions from persistent storage"

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I use Eclipse Kepler to develop a Sprig/Hibernate/PostgreSQL-based application. The application is run in Tomcat which is managed by Eclipse. This works fine generally.

After modifying and saving any jsp about 10 times I get the following exception:

```
Jan 17, 2014 9:53:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/app] has started
Jan 17, 2014 9:53:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
Jan 17, 2014 9:53:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[DEBUG] [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] 17.01.14 09:53:33] (Utils.java:logSystemState:365) System Info: active sessions:  1, availableProcessors:  8, maxMemory: 1754 MB, totalMemory:  658 MB, freeMemory:  110 MB, loadAverage: 0.11
[DEBUG] [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] 17.01.14 09:53:33] (LifeCycle.java:destroy:89) APP 1.1.4 (built on Fri, 17.01.2014, 09:55), destroyed at /app, running on target environment 'dev'. Uptime: 1 hour, 4 minutes, 7 seconds and 314 milliseconds. Spring: 3.2.6.RELEASE, Hibernate: 4.2.8.Final
Jan 17, 2014 9:53:33 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/app] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jan 17, 2014 9:53:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jan 17, 2014 9:53:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext

...

Jan 17, 2014 9:53:37 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager startInternal
SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.app.spring.AuthenticationWrapper
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.CustomObjectInputStream.resolveClass(CustomObjectInputStream.java:76)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1610)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1769)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1595)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:284)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3954)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Jan 17, 2014 9:53:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/app] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 17, 2014 9:53:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 17, 2014 9:53:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/app] is completed
```

The only solution to this is to stop Tomcat, do `Project->Clean`, and restart Tomcat. Of course the session is lost and I have to log into the application again.

This problem is seriously affecting my development workflow, and so far I did not find a solution.

Suspecting a filesystem issue, I have tried to create a folder in tmpfs and used it as server path for Tomcat (setting in Eclipse), but it did not change anything.

*Note that this is only happening on my laptop (Kubuntu 13.10) A colleague has the same laptop with the same OS and does not see the problem.*

It seems the problem is that the session is getting corrupted on the filesystem and Tomcat chokes on that. Why is it happening ?

Answer (score 3):

One way to make this error go away would be to disable session persistence across restarts. You can do this by editing the file **CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml** and setting the pathname attribute of the `<Manager>` to an empty string.

You should also delete any old **session.ser** files from the **CATALINA_HOME/work/Catalina/localhost/<appName>** folder whilst Tomcat is shutdown.

This happens may be because Tomcat didn't shutdown cleanly and so session objects got corrupted during serialization.

Comment: Sure it would make the error go away. But in the sense "If you dont like the noise of your broken exhaust, just don't drive the car" :-) I am looking to actually fix the error. I have a second laptop where I use the same setup (only distro is Fedora) and there it never happens.

Comment: nothing like copying the answer from another thread - Raj - check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622746/exception-loading-sessions-from-persistent-storage  If you need session persistence there maybe more advice there...I didn't flag as duplicate as you are looking for debug advice too (not just the workaround)

Comment: This way you are just hiding the error. And maybe postponing a serious problem.