# Exception loading sessions from persistent storage, extended

Tags: java, tomcat7, ubuntu-16.04

I get

```
Aug 25, 2017 3:35:42 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectStreamClass
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1511)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1608)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1074)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:465)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5593)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1091)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1980)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and

```
((HttpSession) getContextProperty("Session")).setAttribute(name, value);
```

throws

```
Fri Aug 25 15:35:47 GMT+01:00 2017
Server Exception. ID: 72acb94e_15e19d20417_12
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at de.supportgis.gdi.gdigui.GDIApplication.setSessionAttribute(GDIApplication.java:187)
        at de.supportgis.gdi.gdigui.GDIApplication.setCurrentUserLocale(GDIApplication.java:156)
        at de.supportgis.gdi.gdigui.components.StandardContentPanel.getLS(StandardContentPanel.java:236)
        at de.supportgis.gdi.gdigui.content.Login.<init>(Login.java:68)
        at de.supportgis.gdi.gdigui.GDIApplication.init(GDIApplication.java:62)
        at nextapp.echo.app.ApplicationInstance.doInit(ApplicationInstance.java:288)
        at nextapp.echo.webcontainer.UserInstance.prepareApplicationInstance(UserInstance.java:484)
        at nextapp.echo.webcontainer.ComponentInputProcessor.process(ComponentInputProcessor.java:160)
        at nextapp.echo.webcontainer.ClientMessage.process(ClientMessage.java:194)
        at nextapp.echo.webcontainer.InputProcessor.process(InputProcessor.java:163)
        at nextapp.echo.webcontainer.Synchronization.process(Synchronization.java:121)
        at nextapp.echo.webcontainer.service.SynchronizeService.service(SynchronizeService.java:78)
        at nextapp.echo.webcontainer.WebContainerServlet.process(WebContainerServlet.java:432)
        at de.supportgis.gdi.gdigui.StartServlet.process(StartServlet.java:37)
        at nextapp.echo.webcontainer.WebContainerServlet.doPost(WebContainerServlet.java:316)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I guess this is no duplicate, because I checked and applied every answer in [exception loading sessions from persistent storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622746/exception-loading-sessions-from-persistent-storage) with no luck, for example:

- Delete /var/cache/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/gdi/SESSIONS.ser (which is non-existent anyway if Tomcat is stopped).

---

I have no broken symlinks:

```
find / -xtype l 2>/dev/null
```

returns nothing relevant.

---

I guess it is a file system rights problem coming from an `apt dist-upgrade`. Do I really have to reinstall the hole server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `GDIApplication.setSessionAttribute` (second stacktrace) calls `getContextProperty("Session")` which leads to an NPE?

The method `ApplicationInstance.getContextProperty("Session")` belongs to the Echo Framework (https://github.com/echo3/echo3). I'm not exactly sure how it gets hold of the Session object, but the ClassCastException in the first stacktrace might interfere with it.

Try replacing

```
((HttpSession) getContextProperty("Session")).setAttribute(name, value);
```

with

```
Connection conn = WebContainerServlet.getActiveConnection();
conn.getRequest().getSession().setAttribute(name, value);
```

This gives you access to the current ServletRequest and lets you retrieve the session using Java's `ServletRequest.getSession()` method, which will create the session if it doesn't yet exist.

As for the ClassCastException during session recreation: I don't know any other way than the ones you have already tried. But if the above tip works, these exceptions may still be annoying, but could turn out to be harmless. I confess, I normally ignore them when they appear...

Answer (score 1):

clean files from \work\Catalina\localhost folder resolved the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).